# popoto.js - predefine cypher queries

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

i really do like this graph query build for cypher queries of popoto.js, but i would like to predefine often used cypher queries, is it possible somehow "to inject" some queries?

http://www.popotojs.com/examples.html

Especially here: http://www.popotojs.com/live/graph-results/index.html
You can create the query by clicking (top) and the results(bottom), but just visually. But i would like to have multiple buttons for some standard queries without going the visual way.

thanks :)

Comment: checkout popoto.js in src/ directory and try to play with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In latest version ([1.1.2](http://www.popotojs.com/release/popoto-1.1.2.zip)) you have access to new functions to open or save a graph in a predefined state.

See a simple example [here](http://www.popotojs.com/live/save/index.html). You can have a look directly in page source to see details.

In short you can use these code samples to implement this kind of feature:

```
// This property will add a save icon in graph:
popoto.tools.SAVE_GRAPH = true;

// Add a listener on graph save icon click where you can save the graph
popoto.graph.onSave(function (graph) {/* save your graph here */});

// Or get current graph schema at any time that can be saved
popoto.graph.getSchema();

// Start can be called with a saved graph
popoto.start(savedGraph);

// This can also be done at any time to load a graph
popoto.graph.setDefaultGraph(savedGraph);
popoto.tools.reset();
```